# How to round all values in pandas dataframe with certain decimal points

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I am trying to round decimal points in pandas Data Frame, I tried with df.round(4),
if the value is 1.23456 it's converting 1.2346, but I am expecting 1.2345, Please find below code and my dummy data frame, output I got from df.round() function and expected output.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[2.45623786, 5.752739399,77.9488494,66.7477474733,929999.883838978], "Col2":["A","B","C","D","F"],"Col3":["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"], "Col4":["2022-01-01","2022-01-02 12:33:45","2022/12/12","20221123","2022/12/23"],"Col5":[12,233,6464,775,86543334]})
print(df1.head())
df2 = df1.round(6)
print(df2.head)
```

Actual Data

[image]

Output from df1.round(3) function

[image]

Expected output would be

[image]

Thanks in Advance........

Answer (score 0):

You can try using math.floor() function which round down the number, if this is what you want.

Comment: I am expecting to round values in entire dataframe, not for single value